# How to get all users who are not member of a particular group in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How to get all users who are not member of a particular group in Symfony?

Users and Groups have a Many To Many relationship.

I would like to get all users who are not member of the Group with group_id 8, what is an appropriate Entity Query for this in Symfony 2 + Doctrine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `MEMBER OF` might be the one you're looking for. Should be something among the lines:

```
$entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('u')
    ->from('AppBundle:User', 'u')
    ->where(':targetGroup NOT MEMBER OF u.groups')
    ->setParameter('targetGroup', $group)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

That would require of course to do extra query beforehand.

```
 // Find and get instance of the group any way you like.
 $group = $entityManager->find('AppBundle:Group', 8);
```

More to read on query selectors - [Here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples)

The query might need some tweaks, but it should be a good start for you. If you have any problems, don't hesitate to ask.